# How to return a random show function effect with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, random, eval

I'm trying to show some element with a random effect.

I store those functions in an array and try to get a random function from that array, but the functions seem to rum at the same time.

```
$.random_show = function(){
            (function($) {
            $.rand = function(arg) {
                if ($.isArray(arg)) {
                    return arg[$.rand(arg.length)];
                } else if (typeof arg === "number") {
                    return Math.floor(Math.random() * arg);
                } else {
                    return 4;  // chosen by fair dice roll
                }
                };
            })(jQuery);

            $.hide1 = function(){
                alert ('right');
                $('.feed_g_audio_holder_overlay').show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 700);
            }
            $.hide2 = function(){
                alert ('left');
                $('.feed_g_audio_holder_overlay').show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 700);
            }
            $.hide3 = function(){
                alert ('down');
                $('.feed_g_audio_holder_overlay').slideDown();
            }

            var hide_array = [$.hide1(), $.hide2(), $.hide3()];
            return $.rand(hide_array);
            }
```

Where am I getting this wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this:

```
var hide_array = [$.hide1(), $.hide2(), $.hide3()];
```

to:

```
var hide_array = [$.hide1, $.hide2, $.hide3];
```

When you say `$.hide1()` you are calling the function, but you need to return the function reference, *that is why all the functions seem to run at the same time..*

***update:***
 Then to execute the randomly chosen function you can say:

```
$.random_show()
```

or change your return to:

```
return $.rand(hide_array)();
```

Comment: Did that, none of the functions run.

Comment: Yes, according to your code the caller shall run the randomly selected function.

Comment: This "return $.rand(hide_array)();" does it.